# Shared a ko.computed between two ViewModels Knockoutjs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvvm, knockout.js

So I have the following ko.computed:

```
  self.grandTotal = ko.computed(function () {
        var total = self.bookBasePrice();

        if (self.TornEdge() == true)
            total += self.TornEdgeCost();

        if (self.LogoStamping() == true)
            total += self.LogoCost();

        return total;
    });
```

I want to share this between two ViewModels. I have `StartViewModel` and `UploadViewModel` and I use `ko.mapping` to dynamically create the observables and these two ViewModels use exactly the same `grandTotal` computed observable though they differ in other respects.

Is there a good way to do this, I looked at ko.extenders but this not exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: Because I have two views.

Comment: Sorry a little smartass, the views vary significantly, thus the ViewModels computed values and ko.validations differ pretty significantly too, its nice to have two Javascript files organizing this code and keeping it separate and tidy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems like a good candidate to use inheritance, something like this:

```
function BaseVM(){
    var self = this;
    self.someValue = ko.observable();
    self.grandTotal = ko.computed(function () {
       return self.someValue()+1; 
    });
}

function Vm1(initValue){
    var self = this;
    self.someValue(initValue);
}

Vm1.prototype = new BaseVM();
Vm1.prototype.constructor=Vm1;



function Vm2(){
    var self = this;
    self.someValue(13); 
}

Vm2.prototype = new BaseVM();
Vm2.prototype.constructor=Vm2;


ko.applyBindings(new Vm1(4),document.getElementById("View1"));
ko.applyBindings(new Vm2(),document.getElementById("View2"));
```

Fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/luisvsilva/freLc1nd/3/

Usually when I use inheritance in Javascript I use this great snippet form the awesome John Resig:

http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/

Comment: Yes, use Javascript alot but creating a BaseClass, something I do daily in C# eludes me in Javascript, I have never used inheritance in Javascript before

Comment: Is "Vm2.prototype.constructor=Vm1;" supposed to be "Vm2.prototype.constructor=Vm2;" ?

Comment: Yes..well spotted, updated the answer, it the fiddle working for you?

Comment: My bad. I have HttpsEverywhere add on for chrome. Since it appears to load from a CDN, Knockout was getting..... knocked out.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use an ordinary function. So:

```
self.grandTotal = myGrandTotaller;
```

And then define that function:

```
function myGrandTotaller(self) {
        var total = self.bookBasePrice();

        if (self.TornEdge() == true)
            total += self.TornEdgeCost();

        if (self.LogoStamping() == true)
            total += self.LogoCost();

        return total;
    }
```

And then your binding syntax for say, a text box, would be:

```
data-bind="value:grandTotal($root)"
```

I'd favour composition over inheritance for this because you've said they are two very different views / models. So if there is not an "is a" relationship here, I'd go for "has a" i.e. composition.

Comment: Hmm I just marked the other answer as correct, the only think here, is that this would not be a ko.computed observable. With the ko.computed observable if self.TornEdgeCost() were to change a ko.computed grandTotal would update automatically but this solution would not. But I see your point about composition over inheritance

Comment: @BrianOgden No, it does actually update. If  `self.TornEdgeCost()` changed, the UI, including `grandTotal` would update accordingly. The binding is running off `$root` you could also use `$data` in a different scenario. Either way, it runs just the same as a `ko.computed()`... when the model values change the whole thing is updated... otherwise what would be the point right? ;-)

Comment: I have not used $root before or it has too long to remember, thanks for your help...so $root is the "parent" knockout object?

Comment: No `$parent` is the parent. `$root` is the main view model. In your case they may be the same thing assuming you don't have nested binding contexts. Check it out here : http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html . If your model changes i.e. `self.TornEdgeCost()` or whatever, that's going to trigger a rebind. And since you would be binding to `value:grandTotal($root)` it will recompute. This is a fairly standard way of getting around `ko.computable`'s lack of support for parameters. Also note as above `$data` might also be the way to go in another context.